# Assignment from the old to the new array Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

I have to array, I try assignment array liczba to liczba2

```
var liczba:[Int]=[1,2,3,4]
var liczba2:[Int]=[]

var rozmiar=0
for var i=0;i<liczba.count;++i{
    for var j=0;j<liczba2.count;++j{
    liczba[i]=liczba2[++rozmiar]
    }
}

print(liczba2)
```

What  do wrong ?

Comment: Quite a few wrong things in your code. Both `++` and C-style `for` loop have been deprecated and will be removed from Swift 3. But first: what are you trying to do? What's the expected output look like?

Comment: yes, try to explain your problem better

Comment: I have try assignment array liczba on liczba 2 . The array liczba2 show numbers as array liczba. The array liczba2 show output 1,2,3,4

Comment: check my answer @MagdalenaDziesińska

Comment: You can just write: `var liczba2 = liczba`

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE** : I understand that `liczba2 = liczba` works perfectly. But, I want to show the below code to @MagdalenaDziesińska, so that she can learn the syntax.

This copies elements of `liczba` to `licbza2`

```
var liczba:[Int]=[1,2,3,4]
var liczba2:[Int]=[]

var rozmiar=0
    for element in liczba {
    liczba2.append(element)
    }
    print(liczba2)
```

Comment: @MagdalenaDziesińska I am so sorry, I am Indian. Not very accustomed to names outside my Indian domain. Sorry again..  Hope my answer helped :)